# Calculating p-value and adjusted p-value for pre-normalized microarray data with fold change calculated

Tags: biostatistics, bioinformatics, genetics, microarray, omics

I have a microarray dataset that has already been normalized, and the fold change values for each gene in the mutant versus the wild type have been calculated. I'm interested in determining the statistical significance of these fold changes.

Given that I only have the fold change values (and no raw intensity or count data), what would be the best approach to calculate the p-values and adjusted p-values for each gene? I'm looking for a method that can help me identify genes that are significantly upregulated or downregulated in the mutant compared to the wild type.

Any guidance, recommended tools, or R packages would be greatly appreciated!